# How to handle asynchronous tasks with queues defined on a user (or other attribute) basis with django and celery?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, celery, celery-task

thank you for viewing my question. I am new to celery and I am trying to wrap my head around the world of threading and multiprocessing, but I cannot seem to find any info that fits my specific use case.

Consider this, I have a django-rest-framework API for my personal trading software that receives post requests to perform a buy or sell order to my broker's REST API.

Now, I want to make sure that my API can handle numerous concurrent requests and queue those requests and process those in the order that they were received. One task cannot happen before the other if finished because the next task will rely on database information that the former task has written.

I have implemented a celery instance to process a FIFO queue. Here lies my question, lets say I have multiple strategies, and I don't want the queues from multiple strategies to be mixed in the same queue. I want an asynchronous queue per strategy. Do I now require multiple worker instances, or can I separate queues into one worker instance?

What exactly would that syntax look like or what celery methods should I be looking in to?

**The post request view**

```
@csrf_exempt
def webhook(request, username, slug):
    webhook_data = json.loads(request.body)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        webhook_queue.delay(username,slug,request.body)
        return HttpResponse(response)
```

**The celery task**

```
@task(name='webhook_queue')
def webhook_queue(username,slug,webhook_data):
    strategy = UserStrategyModel.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug,user__username__iexact=username)
    user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=username)
    webhook = Webhook(webhook=webhook_data,strategy=strategy,user=user).process_webhook() 
    logger.info('Webhook processing.')
```